# Breakout project painting all bricks on top of each other

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, breakout

I am coding a breakout game in android studio. I have set up the bricks in an array and have them set up to be painted. However, all of the bricks are painted on top of each other.

BreakoutView class extract:

```
private static final int rows = 5;
private static final int columns = 10;
private static final int brickHeight = 50;
private static final int brickWidth = 100;
int brickX = 0;
int brickY = 0;
int brickSpaces = 0;
private Sprite[] bricks;

public BreakoutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bricks = new Sprite[rows * columns];
    for (Sprite brick: bricks) {
        brick.setSize(brickWidth, brickHeight);
        brick.setLocation(brickX, brickY);
        brick.paint.setARGB(255,250,0,0);
    }
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (Sprite brick : bricks) {
        for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
            brickY = brickHeight + brickSpaces;
            for (int c = 0; c <= columns; c++) {
                brickX = brickWidth + brickSpaces;
                brickSpaces = 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sprite class:

```
public class Sprite {

    public RectF rect = new RectF();
    public float dx = 0;
    public float dy = 0;
    public Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Sprite(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        setLocation(x, y);
        setSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code posted here doesn't create any Sprites. Please post the smallest block of code that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

First, you are creating an empty array, then looping through all the (non-existent) objects in that array.

Second, it looks like you want this code to control where the bricks go:

```
for (Sprite brick : bricks) {
    for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
        brickY = brickHeight + brickSpaces;
        for (int c = 0; c <= columns; c++) {
            brickX = brickWidth + brickSpaces;
            brickSpaces = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

... except that it doesn't update the x and y in the brick object itself. Perhaps you forgot to call `brick.setLocation(brickX, brickY)`?

Also, you are looping through all locations for all bricks. Which means that all bricks will get the last position that the loop produced.

Your loop should probably work this way:

```
for (Sprite brick : bricks) {
    // work out where this particular brick goes (rather than loop through them all)
    brickX = ?;
    brickY = ?;

    // set the location into the sprite
    brick.setLocation(brickX, brickY);
}
```